# How to open system's command line at the directory of the current buffer?

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, shell-command

Is there any easy way to open the system command line interface (e.g., `cmd` in Windows) at the directory containing the current buffer (if any)? Note that `M-x shell` open a command line interface within emacs, hence does not answer the question. I also tried `M-x shell-command cmd` but this also open the command line interface within emacs.

Comment: What happens if you type `!` on directory name and then `cmd` when prompted for the program to run? I cannot test this on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I don't understand by what you mean to type `!` on directory name and then `cmd`. Do you mean to do `M-!` then giving `cmd`?

Comment: In `dired` buffer `!` is bound to `dired-do-shell-command`, so pressing it would be similar to `M-!` except Emacs automatically sets some parameteres for the command invoked, such as "current directory".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `start cmd` to get a new terminal window.  Use `M-&` (`async-shell-command`) to avoid blocking Emacs.  This creates a useless `*Async Shell Command*` buffer, you can use the `start-process-shell-command` function to avoid this:

```el
(start-process-shell-command (format "cmd(%s)" default-directory) nil "start cmd")
```

Comment: This gives the desired behaviour only if `default-directory` is not set, because in that case, Emacs seems to resort to using the directory of the buffer you are in. If, however, you did set `default-directory`, then the terminal will always open in that directory, neglecting the folder you are in. See my answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63733/23812) if you want the behaviour to be "launch in current folder" even when you have set `default-directory`.

Comment: @kotchwane Yeah, Emacs generally considers the value of `default-directory` to be "the folder you are in", by definition. If you change `default-directory` in a file-visiting buffer, there are two plausible values for "folder you are in", but fixing that is IMO a separate question.