# Launch an external command prompt (cmd.exe) in a specific folder

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell

I'm trying to build a `cmd` interactive function in Emacs, which would open a Windows command prompt - exactly like `Win+R` `cmd` does. Within Emacs, it would be accessible with `M-x` `cmd`, and it would open the Windows terminal on the current folder.

The reason I want to build this function is that there are cases where the Emacs shell does not give the outputs properly (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007503/why-my-emacs-does-not-display-shells-output)), and in these cases I'd like to open a Windows terminal quickly, and at the location I'm at.

I know how to get the current folder in Emacs, but I can't seem to find how to launch the Windows console from Emacs. `call-process` works for programs like firefox.exe or explorer.exe, yet when I try the following, nothing appears (it doesn't matter if I write the full path or not):

```
(call-process "cmd.exe")
```

**TL;DR**: So, what would be the command to launch, from Emacs, an **external** command prompt at a specific path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following, which works:

```lisp
(defun cmd()
  "Open an external Windows cmd in the current directory"
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory
      (if (buffer-file-name)
               (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))
               default-directory))))
    (call-process-shell-command "start cmd"))
```

The idea to use `start cmd` instead of `cmd` comes from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303838/create-a-new-cmd-exe-window-from-within-another-cmd-exe-prompt): it's the standard way to open a new `cmd` from a runnning one, in Windows.
The idea to use `call-process-shell-command` comes from multiple tries and errors.